# How to control of display the number of digit in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

I want to ask a question about the JSP and Java. I am writing the JSP page and has a bean class. In the class, i have a getter function which will return a double var in the jsp page. I used the following code to display the number.

```
<p> the value of AB is <%=obj.getValue() %> <p>
```

I expect that display will like the following

```
the value of AB is 0.45
```

However, the real display is the following

```
the value of AB is 0.4569877987
```

I only want to display the last two digit. What should I do in order to display what I want. Should I modify the JSP page or the Java class variable? thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `DecimalFormat` to format the value as a string, e.g.:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
```

(the pattern assumes you always want two digits in the fractional part, even if the fractional part is zero. Otherwise, use `#0.##`)

However in general it is recommended not to call the `DecimalFormat` constructors directly. Instead, the recommended practice is to call one of the factory methods of `NumberFormat`, then customize the pattern as needed, e.g.:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
```

Javadoc including examples:

- http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html
- http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

This should work in your JSP page:

```
<%@ page import="java.text.NumberFormat" %>
<%
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
%>

[...]

<p> the value of AB is <%= nf.format(obj.getValue()) %> <p>
```

Also see Bozho's answer for a way to achieve the same result using JSTL.

Answer (score 12):

In JSP you can do this using the JSTL tag [`<fmt:formatNumber>`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatNumber.html). You can set either a `pettern` (`#0.##`) or `maxFractionDigits="2"`

Avoid using Java code in JSPs - use JSTL instead. [See this tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html). And see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 4):

To answer your last question first - you should modify the JSP page, since you want to change how the number is *displayed*, not what the number actually *is*.

To do this, instead of invoking the number's default toString method, you could use a [DecimalFormat](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) object to convert the number to text in whatever format you want.  In this case, you probably want to use:

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.##")
```

as the format string.

**However**, [as per Bozho's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904505/how-to-control-of-display-the-number-of-digit-in-jsp/3904606#3904606) there is a JSTL tag to achieve this, which is a better way to solve your problem.